# Ошибка при компиляции проекта: A reference to an enclosing class is requiered

Tags: java, android

И так, делаю VPN клиент и получаю непонятную ошибку...

> A reference to an enclosing class is requiered

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Запрос прав на подключение VPN...

        Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }


    // Права полученны...


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode) {
        if (requestCode == BIND_AUTO_CREATE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            VpnService.Builder bb = new VpnService.Builder();

        }
    }
}
```

> new VpnService.Builder()
>   Этот кусок кода подкреслен красным..не компилиться!

Может ктото знает что нужно сделать?
Чего не хватает? И что я делаю не так.

Comment: в каком месте (строчке) возникает ошибка? добавьте код `VpnService`

Comment: new VpnService.Builder(); Этот кусок кода подкреслен красным..не компилиться!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, класс `Builder` – это внутренний (*inner*) класс класса `VpnService`. Инстанс внутреннего класса можно создать только в контексте внешнего класса.

Тут два решения: либо объявить класс `Builder` статическим вложенным (*static nested*) классом (добавить модификатор `static`) – такие классы могут существовать отдельно от внешнего класса, либо создавать инстанс класса `Builder` в контексте класса `VpnService` (имея его инстанс).

**UPD**:

```
public class VpnService {

    public static class Builder {

    }
}
```

Теперь где-то извне можно создать инстанс билдера:

```
VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
```

Comment: А как объявить класс Builder статическим вложенным?

Comment: Укажите пример с моим кодом..

Comment: @Вадим, Замените `class Builder` на `static class Builder`.

Comment: Сверавно не роботает..

Comment: Всеравно  не роботает скиньте готовое решение если не сложно... Никак не получается

Comment: @Вадим, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Тоже не роботает значение static подчеркнуто красным, а создаваемый обект builder определяется как MainActivity.VpnService.Builder() а должен определяться как VpnService.Builder() это важно!!! Пожалуйста тестируйте код перед тем как отправлять.

Comment: @Вадим, Так как Вы не предоставили минимальный воспроизводимый пример, то я тестирую как есть и у меня все работает.